# What are the most valuable skills to learn to be considered for a quantum optics PhD position?

Tags: phd, physics

I have a master degree in thin-films interferometry, and I want to receive a Ph.D position in the area of Quantum optics. How can I assure receiving this position? What are the required skills or certificates to be accepted?

Comment: Close voters, how is this a shopping question?

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping

Answer (score 1):

You can get a PhD position without specific knowledge of the research area.  For quantum optics, commonly desired skills include:

- English language skills
- Advanced mathematical skills, including statistics
- Broad education in physics
- Experience conducting research

You do not need a "certificate."  You will need a masters degree (which can substitute for a bachelors degree in countries that require a bachelors degree).